# How to enableviewstate from code behind for the whole page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where i have set EnableViewState = 'False', but for certain cases, like CMS admin page, i want the EnableViewState to be set to True from code behind. I tried to put the code in Page_Load, but doesnot seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that in the page's `OnInit` event instead of `Page_Load`. See [Page.OnInit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd6at422(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

As this [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle tutorial](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/performance/page-life-cycle-in-asp-net/) shows, the `OnInit` is your last chance to turn on/off `ViewState`.